# Как запустить файл по его расширению?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Подскажите, как запускать файл, например с расширением `*.txt` через приложение, которое увидит его расширение и запустит форму?

Например, берем файл `test.txt` и перетаскиваем его на приложение, если файл содержит расширение `*.txt`, то приложение открывает форму, если файл содержит расширение `*.jpg`, то приложение выведет окно с ошибкой.

Есть пример, но на именных файлах:

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Главная точка входа для приложения.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var whitelist = new HashSet<string>{@"C:\test.txt", @"C:\test2.txt"};
        if (args.Any() && whitelist.Contains(args[0]))
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Файл не прошел проверку");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего, вам нужно сделать так

```
if (args.Any() && args[0].EndsWith(".txt"))
  {
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Form1());
  }
  else
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Файл не прошел проверку");
  }
```

С учетом дополнения

```
var whitelist = new HashSet<string>{".txt", ".jpg"};

if (args.Any() && whitelist.Contains(Path.GetExtension(args[0])))
{
   Application.EnableVisualStyles();
   Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
   Application.Run(new Form1());
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Файл не прошел проверку");
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! работает :)

Comment: наверное лучше не `Contains`, а `EndsWith`?

Comment: VladD спасибо, так тоже работает :)

Comment: Немного не подумал, не хватает перечисления расширений: `.txt, .jpg` и т.д. (без перечисления придется под каждое расширение создавать свое приложение)

Comment: @Vitokhv дополнил

Comment: @Lolidze спасибо за Ваши труды, очень помогли!