# Белый список расширений в реестре (внутри приложения)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Подскажите, на основе темы: [Как запустить файл по его расширению?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/764061/)

Как добавить в приложение проверку расширений через реестр?

Например, текстовой файл запускается через приложение, приложение отправляет команду в реестр для проверки списка расширений. Если расширение файла совпадает с ключом реестра содержащий: *.txt, приложение открывает свою форму.

Проблема в том, что для изменения имен файлов и расширений внутри приложения, необходимо каждый раз обновлять его и весь список имен и расширений. Приведенный способ через реестр поможет обновлять список без необходимости обновлять приложение.

p.s. желательно, чтобы каждое расширение имело свой ключ в реестре

Пример кода с белым списком внутри приложения:

```
var whitelist = new HashSet<string>{".txt", ".jpg"};

if (args.Any() && whitelist.Contains(Path.GetExtension(args[0])))
{
   Application.EnableVisualStyles();
   Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
   Application.Run(new Form1());
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Файл не прошел проверку");
}
```

Comment: Извините, непонятно, что именно вам нужно. Вы хотите сделать какую-то проверку через реестр. Что именно вы хотите сравнить? Что с чем ? (я вам внёс правку в вопрос - посмотрите о чём речь) Расширение файла с чем? И, может вам нужен [подобный механизм](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/759297/213987)? Т.е. в реестре закрепляется список расширений, которые обрабатывает ваша программа?

Comment: Поправил. Нужно первую строчку кода поместить в реестр, чтобы приложение считывало белый список из реестра, а не внутри себя. Ваше описание про механизм подходит, но для меня оно сложно в понимании. Приложение должно обрабатывать список расширений в реестре.

Comment: То есть в ответе вы хотите видеть [чтение ключа реестра  в c#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0) и всё? Или нужно ещё в ответ добавить как записывать в реестр из приложения? Или рядом с ПО будет лежать reg-файл? (Может ваш вопрос задубликатить на что-то похожее, м?)

Comment: Достаточно, чтобы приложение читало расширения в реестре отдельными ключами. Например ключ с именем "TXT" содержит: *.txt

Comment: А давайте договоримся а) не на набор ключей, а на один ключ, мультистроковый параметр handled_extensions и б) на строки `txt` вместо `*.txt` как вам? Ведь явно проще же будет самому работать.

Comment: Инсталлятор из студии умеет в систему добавлять пользовательские расширения, посмотрите, может вам интеграция студии подойдёт, чтоб велосипед не изобретать.

Comment: (A K) Я не всю картину вижу как Вы, если правильнее написать просто txt то конечно вариант б). Но к сожалению мультистроковый параметр будет перечислять все расширения в одном ключе, это приведет к очень большому списку, который придется изменять полностью весь...

Comment: (A K) Вариант а). тоже устраивает, т.к. не осталось решений...

Answer (score 1):

Вы слишком усложняете себе задачу. В современном мире реестром принято пользоваться только в случае необходимости взаимодействовать с сервисами, которые завязаны на реестр. Обычно это связано с операционной системой и старыми приложениями с царским наследием.

Гораздо более удобно как с точки зрения программиста, так и с точки зрения пользователя (а также кроссплатформенно) — хранить настройки в файле. В Windows это `%APPDATA%` (`C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Roaming`). По вкусу можно использовать хоть XML, хоть JSON. Проекты .NET в Visual Studio даже имеют [встроенные средства для хранения настроек приложения](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa730869.aspx) (мне они кажутся недостаточно гибкими, но зато не надо писать код от слова вообще).

Программисту такой подход удобнее, потому что настройки читать легче, чем реестр — меньше кода. Пользователю такой подход удобнее, потому что легче редактировать настройки и переносить их между компьютерами (эти настройки даже перенесутся автоматически внутри домена, как и всё в Roaming App Data).

Так что можете добавить в проект файл настроек (`.settings`), добавить строковое свойство `SupportedExtensions` = `txt;jpg`, а потом проверять имя файла примерно так:

```
Settings.Default.SupportedExtensions.Split(';').Contains(Path.GetExtension(args[0]));
```

Не понимаю, что у вас за проблемы с "изменением всей строки целиком". По-моему, вы усложняете задачу на пустом месте, возможно, из-за попыток микрооптимизации.

Comment: К сожалению белый список должен быть в столбик. Чтобы значения проверялись отдельно, а не целой строкой все в куче. Это нужно для того, чтобы привязывать полные имена файлов, которых будет не мало и их трудно будет редактировать внутри одной строки.

Comment: @Vitokhv Файл настроек (и реестр) — не для того, чтобы его редактировать, а для того, чтобы сериализовать туда настройки. Для управления же настройками пишется нормальный пользовательский интерфейс. / Если вы настаиваете на редактировании файла напрямую или какой-то конкретном формате (XML, JSON, YAML...), то создайте класс со свойством `List<string> Extensions` и сериализуйте в удобный вам формат.

Comment: Пуст будет в строчку, но в реестре. Вы как профессионал знаете как лучше для Вас, мне как начинающему трудно ориентироваться, могу только с реестром работать.